# Are ApplicationContext or Activity Context suitable for Adapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I am using the adapter for ListView/RecycleView on my project. But I am wondering which kind of **Context** I should pass to the adapter? **ApplicationContext** or **Activity Context**(it's mean this on the activity)?. 
As I know that the system does not kill the adapter even if the activity being killed. So I have some confusions here:

1. If I pass the **Activity Context** to the adapter, so the adapter have an implicit reference to the activity. Can the activity be killed?
2. In the other hand, I pass ApplicationContext. How long does the Adapter still live? Does it collected by GC after the activity be killed?
3. Which kind of **Context** I should pass in specific case?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If I pass the Activity Context to the adapter, so the adapter have an
>   implicit reference to the activity. Can the activity be killed?

Correction it is an **explicit reference** since you are passing it manually. So basically the answer to your question is likely YES because the one holding the Adapter is the activity itself, even if the adapter is holding a reference to your activity both of them will be garbage collected once the Activity is finished.

Unless you are dealing with Threads it is recommended to use `WeakReference` since a Thread can live longer than the activity itself.

> In the other hand, I pass ApplicationContext. How long does the
>   Adapter still live? Does it collected by GC after the activity be
>   killed?

YES

> Which kind of Context I should pass in specific case?

Both can work but Application context is a lot safer.

> As I know that the system does not kill the adapter even if the
>   activity being killed.

Something is not right in the code, probably you are dealing the wrong use of statics or Threads. *Additional code required here or a proof of your profiler!*

Comment: Really helpful and clear to understand. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

ApplicationContext as it should get cleaned by GC when you destroy the activity if you have more than 1

Comment: Thanks, but Can you explain more detail about "more than 1" ?

Comment: If you have more than 1 activity

Comment: The best is to use getContext in the App file and get the current context from it every time you need it

Answer (score 3):

While using RecyclerView, (which you should prefer to ListView), you most likely will implement `RecyclerView.Adapter`. One of the methods you have to override there `onCreateViewHolder`, provides you with the context you should use:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // Use this context
    Context context = parent.getContext()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion of using RecyclerView instead of ListView.
About parent.getContext(), I go to this method and get descriptions are: "Returns the context the view is running in, through which it can access the current theme, resources, etc. " So the Context returned is view's Context, it means Activity Context. As my question above, I am wondering about which kind of Context I should use in the adapter. 
Can you tell me why did you choose Activity Context instead of ApplicationContext ?